# HTTP-Methods understanding: Why does the documentation use PUT instead of POST in this AWS API Gateway Integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-method, amazon-kinesis

In a project, we are using AWS Kinesis Firehose for Data Ingestion.

To access it from the Browser and without Authentication I set up an AWS API Gateway to set up a public endpoint. To Ingest Data into Firehose you are supposed to use the [`PutRecords`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) Method.

In the Documentation on how to set up Kinesis Firehose with API Gateway it says I am supposed to use a PUT-Method, which uses a [POST-Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html#:%7E:text=To%20set%20up%20and%20test%20the%20PUT%20/streams/%7Bstream%2Dname%7D/record%20method%20to%20invoke%20PutRecord%20in%20Kinesis%3A) to putRecord into Kinesis Firehose.

Why do we use a PUT for this API and not a POST? If I understood HTTP methods correctly, POST would make more sense here. I mean we are even using a POST afterwards to write the data into Kinesis Firehose. But why do we use PUT-Mehtod for this API. Any Ideas?